# Tumblr background-attachment: absolute; showing as invalid property value

Tags: html, css

Firstly, I thank whoever takes the time to help me with this issue-- it's been driving me crazy for days.

Basically, my Tumblr theme is the issue here. When I go on it, it looks fine, but when others do, the content is all over the place due to different screen resolutions. There is a way to fix this, so that the background image and blog content lock together on the theme, making them always in the same spot (ex. My background image was made on photoshop, and I created a little box for where I wanted to blog content to appear-- when I'm on the blog, it looks fine, because it's tailored to my 1600x800 screen resolution. However for other people, if they don't have that screen resolution, the blog content isn't in that box).

Below is the body section of my code:

```
body {
    background-image: url('http://imgur.com/4CzbHdZ.png'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:absolute;
    background-size:cover;
    color:{color:text};
    font-family:Ebrima;
    text-transform:none;
    font-size:10px;
    line-height:130%;
    letter-spacing:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

I've also created a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/9YKfsycG

My main issue is the background image. When I zoom in or out, it's supposed to move with the blog content. Instead, it stays locked in place. Upon inspecting the page, I see that the section of my code that reads background-attachment: absolute; is being marked as "invalid property value" by Chrome.

**Note:** Switching it from "absolute" to "fixed" doesn't change anything.

Again, I thank anyone who takes time to look at this and help me with this issue.

If you require screenshots, I do have them - It simply won't allow me to post them here because in order to post more than 2 links, you have to have above a 10 in reputation.

Comment: That's because absolute *is* an invalid value for background-attachment. fixed is a valid value but it may not be the one you're looking for.

Comment: Alright, I changed it to fixed. Like I said, it doesn't change anything, but thank you.

Comment: Valid values, for a global background anyway, are `fixed` and `scroll`. Pick one.

Comment: I added fixed and, upon inspecting the page, it's no longer listed as "invalid property value". However, the background image is still locked in place and won't move with the blog content.

Answer (score 3):

Switching absolute to fixed allowed Chrome to read the code properly. From there, I removed background-size: cover; and got the result I was hoping for. Thank you!

Comment: I can only do that after two days, it says.